# Regular Expression for htaccess redirection in Wordpress (permalinks)

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I want a regular expression for my non seo friendly urls to be converted in something more understandable by normal users. I want to convert

```
http://mywebsite.com/?view=wp&page_id=499&mid=125

to

http://mywebsite.com/text/text
```

Comment: This is impossible without information about the relationship between these URLs. You need to provide more detail.

Comment: This url is generated in my wordpress site and I don't know that reason why and I can't even find this page, so thought of re-directing it to some other page. If it's not possible then will `Redirect 301 /?view=wp&page_id=499&mid=125 /index.php` work?

Comment: You need to edit the permalinks in your Wordpress installation. [See this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for details.